# Strategy for Angular routing

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I see 2 approaches:

1) Define root module as a single source of truth, where all route paths are handled, e.g.

```
const routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}  
  children: [...]
]
```

use only:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

2)

```
const routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeModule}  
]
```

then in HomeModule

```
const homeRoutes = [
  ...
]
```

and use

```
RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)
```

What strategy do you use?

Comment: you should read [official angular guide for routing](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with **option 1** if your application is **small** and will stay small (3-6 views).

But if you have **multiple sub-modules** (think sales app with IventoryModule and UserMangementModule) then **options 2**. That is because you would want routing to locally to the module that it is related to (especially if one day you might package these modules separately).